# Spring KafkListner Connection Pooling

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka Listener with `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`. I have around 400 partitions to listen the data and so I made concurrency = 400. So here does KafkaListenr will make 400 outbound connections or it will make few connection and re-use them?
Can I configure any connection pooling to control number of outbound connections ?

```java
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring for Apache Kafka delegates all connection activity to the `kafka-clients` library.

As far as I know, there is no such pooling available there.